# Install dev dependencies for only a specific git hosted npm package

Tags: npm, npm-install

I'm trying to build an npm package after it is installed from git.

For the package to build I need to have the dev dependencies installed as well. The package is built with webpack and I have listed webpack as a dev dependency.

I have tried setting `--production=false` following way

```
package.json of the package that im trying to install    

{
  // rest of the package.json
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack",
    "install": "npm install --production=false",
    "postinstall": "npm run build"
  }
}
```

I can see that running `npm install` again in the `install` script is stupid.

I can try to only set the `--production=false` for now, but then I guess I'll have to set it back to `--production=true` again and what about dependencies installed in parallel, will this flag affect those too?

Is there any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

By default `npm install` installs `dependencies` and `devDependencies` if the `NODE_ENV` environment variable is not set to `production`. As in development environment we basically need the `devDependencies` as well, I suggest to check the `NODE_ENV` environmental variable and set it to `development`. With this `NODE_ENV` value there is no need for the `--production=false` additional flag. And if you would need to install only the `dependencies` you can call simply `npm install --production`, I would not define an npm script for that.